# How to dynamically change the selectizer setValue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am early bee for jquery. How to set the value dynamically for selectizer.js. The value is not changed in my html. The same value is displaying all the times.

Comment: share some relevent code that you have tried so far so that we can help you better

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setValue` function. [See docs here](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Example:

```html
<select id="selectize" class='select-edit' multiple>
    <option value=opt0>Option 0</option>
    <option value=opt1>Option 1</option>
</select>
```

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectize').selectize();
    var selectize_tags = $("#selectize")[0].selectize;
    selectize_tags.setValue('opt0');
});
```

<kbd>[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/x3b51fts/5/)</kbd>